# Image doesn't show when using Silex and Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

I use [Silex-Skeleton](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton). Twig layout is present in templates directory (templates/layout.html). I store images in web/img directory (top.jpg). I also use built-in php5.4 server running:

```
php -S localhost:8000 web/index_dev.php
```

In templates/layout.html I'd like to use web/img/top.jpg picture. So I put there:

```
<img src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/img/top.jpg">
```

But image doesn't show.

I've also tried:

```
<img src="/img/top.jpg">
<img src="/web/img/top.jpg">
```

But with no success either.

My controller looks like (index.html extends layout.html):

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
  return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array());
})->bind('homepage');
```

What should I do to get images to work?

Comment: Louis van Tonder - thank you for editing. I wanted to change question to a proper one, but while editing I still get a message that code formatting is wrong... The question should be: Silex + Twig - image doesn't show

Comment: Isn't that a question for http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: @jacekpl you should be able to edit your own question

Comment: I thought so, but when I click edit and Save (with no editing at all) I get a message "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.". Strange thing for  me.

Comment: @jacekpl , maybe a plugin in your browser interfering with formatting? Editing works fine... I simply pasted your code in from pastebin... did not change 1 single character.

Comment: @jacekpl strange. I have edited the question, removing the pastebin link and adding the hyperlink. I didn't get an error message so maybe the question is now compliant.

Comment: Now I've edited, saved and  it has worked fine. Strange. I don't use any unusual plugins in my FF31 (Adblock, Firebug, FirePHP, Page Speed and YSlow). Thank you for help.

Comment: Have you tried using assetic in your twig instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you navigate to `http://localhost:8000/web/img/top.jpg` or `http://localhost:8000/img/top.jpg` directly? If you can't browse and see them directly they will not render as the browser will not be able to find them to display on your page either.

Are your images actually in or below the **/web** folder? (i.e. they should not be in your **/templates** folder)

Perhaps you could try to set the docroot explicitly sing the -t option when you launch the [PHP webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

Otherwise I would suggest setting up a real web server like Apache. Your OS may already have this installed if you are running OS X or *nix.

Comment: You are right! I couldn't reach images under web/ folder. Running with -t parameter and no index_dev.php file helped (php -S localhost:8000 -t web/). Thank you.